# How to roleplay vampires that are really representative of their clan?

Tags: world-of-darkness, roleplaying, vampire-the-masquerade

As a storyteller I want to play my NPCs (or SPCs, in the language of V5) in a way that help my players to know which clan they are. To make that, I use clichés and Compulsion of the clans, but that feels to me like it's the wrong way.

**How do I roleplay vampires to make them really representative of their clans?**

Answer (score 2):

### Use the culture of the clan

You want to mention things that are part of the clan's culture. Individuals represent groups by showing **products** or **behaviours** that make them part of that group. Also, if you're the DM you can define a clan's culture in a certain area. Here's a list of things you can include:

**Brujah.** Social awareness, resistance to conservative ideas, political literature, pop culture, Che shirts, Palestinian scarfs, wearing the "SJW" label with pride. Brujah are often depicted as idealistic.

**Gangrel.** Animals, outdoor activities, hunt, domination, action before thought, territoriality, mountain gear, cabin in the woods. Gangrel are often depicted as insular.

**Malkavian.** Conspiracy theories, psychology, pseudoscience, psychoactive drugs, frequent incidents with authority, meticulous planning, oddities, yelling. Malkavian are often depicted as unpredictable.

**Nosferatu.** Computers, secrets, pet rats, shady deals, horror films, social exclusion, dark humor, geekyness. Nosferatu are often depicted as pragmatic.

**Toreador.** Social drugs, clubs, social media, celebrities, big social gatherings, musical instruments, big spending, entourages. Toreador are often depicted as hedonistic.

**Tremere.** Magic, spells, secrets, cults, pentagrams, new age, Wicca, goth jewelry, dim lighted places, Harry Potter books. Tremere are often depicted as mysterious.

**Ventrue.** Business, skyscrapers, office work, suits, public persona, attachment to high standing brands, lawyers. Ventrue are often depicted as self-confident.